Monit averages CPU usage over time
We use Monit (v3.7.10) to monitor the CPU usage of our servers, among other things. We noticed that when we change the time period Monit seems to be doing some averaging. For instance below is the CPU usage for a server with the hour time period selected. We can see the server is mostly above 50% CPU usage all the time and spikes close to 100% a few times. If we then switch to the day time period we can see that Monit seems to be doing averages on CPU usage and all the CPU spikes are smoothed out which is not helping when looking at CPU usage. Is there any way to prevent this averaging and do max of each period instead? Thanks



Its probably doing that because of graph real estate, if it showed real samples it would be 10 miles long. Would be my guess.

For hourly Monit is charting data points every minute. But for daily it's every 15mins. But after further checks I can see that within those 15mins it's doing some sort of average so this has anunwanted side effect of smothing lots of high CPU spikes over time, specially those with a short duration.
